# React Native app sending data to SwiftUI widget

Tags: swift, react-native

I am working on the widget of an app in Swift 5, and the App is written in React-Native, and as I am a beginner, I do know if it is possible to get the location (lat and long), from the app and pass it to the iOS widget.
I have found examples mainly of when the app is also written in Swift, but how it is done, or is it even possible, to pass the data when it is in React-Native?

Also, the sys. req. are for the app iOS 12.0+, and the widget iOS 14.0+

*Added a photo of the skeleton of my project.*
[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5qXn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is possible and I found an article here [React Native Meets SwiftUI](https://medium.com/better-programming/react-native-meets-swiftui-d1606a8e1681)